# Imagemagick: Ignores exact dimensions?

Tags: image, imagemagick

For some reason,

```
-rotate 186.516 -crop 3194x1796+2350+2420 -resize 1920x1080
-rotate 186.522 -crop 3192x1795+2360+2420 -resize 1920x1080
-rotate 186.527 -crop 3190x1794+2370+2420 -resize 1920x1080
```

all output 1920x1080 images, and

```
-rotate 186.533 -crop 3188x1792+2380+2420 -resize 1920x1080
-rotate 186.538 -crop 3186x1791+2390+2420 -resize 1920x1080
-rotate 186.544 -crop 3184x1790+2400+2420 -resize 1920x1080
```

all output 1920x1079-sized images.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but that's not right. What can I do about this, when I absolutely need a 1920x1080 output every time, and prefer to keep this within imagemagick with only one pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `-resize 1920x1080` at the end of each command to  `-resize 1920x1080!` to force exact dimensions.

Comment: brilliant! exactly what I was looking for. thank you Mark